# How to print a big size using QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, paper

Using QGIS to print a map but I cannot choose a size bigger than A4 in the map composer.

How do I print a map for example 841x1189 mm size ?

Comment: From the drop-down containing the sizes, choose 'custom' then enter your dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of paper size is located under the 'Composition' tab. You can select the desired paper size from the 'Page size' drop-down menu, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this section is not in there anymore in QGIS 3.10. (The tab is now called "Layout", but there is no "Page size" section.)
To open it, you will have to right-click on the page and select "Page Properties", which will open the Item Properties tab for the page.